# Remove Leading "0" in day of month SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

Is it possible to remove the "0" in January 04, 2012?

I am currently using the following Java to get the date format like

```
Monday, January 04, 2012
```

I would like for it to look like

```
Monday, January 4, 2012

    Date anotherCurDate = new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE', 'MMMM dd', ' yyyy");  
    final String formattedDateString = formatter.format(anotherCurDate);

 final TextView currentRoomDate = (TextView)  this.findViewById(R.id.CurrentDate);
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE', 'MMMM d', ' yyyy");
```

Should do it (one 'd' instead of two)?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Of course it would be that easy. I figured there was going to be some post process to fix it. Thanks I will test now.

Comment: Hehe, it's called 'simple' date formatter for a reason ;)  I added a link to the documentation for it, in case you haven't seen it.

Comment: The explicit use of single format specifiers is articulated in this Oracle tutorial...
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get a String without "0" in front of a number just by doing this :

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
// If you want the day/month in String format  
String month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH)+""; 

// If you want the day/month in Integer format 
int monthInt = (int ) Integer.parseInt(month);
```