# Remove leading "0" in day and month in jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

My question is similar to [Remove Leading "0" in day of month SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836294/remove-leading-0-in-day-of-month-simpledateformat)

Is it possible to remove the leading "0" in jquery UI datepicker?

The [DateFormat option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) is as close as I could get from the documentation:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

But what I need is on a date like Dec 5th, 2012, datepicker shows it as 12/05/2012 whereas I would like to have 12/5/2012. Same goes for April 5th: 4/5/2013 for example.

Can this be done without an extensive logic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-m-d" });

Source:[Jquery DateFormats](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/%24.datepicker.formatDate)

Comment: Yep, definitely missed that one. Thanks!