# Not able to work with Java Date Function properly

Tags: java, date, datepicker

If I take current date from my application, it comes with variation like below:

**scenario 1:** when the date is less than 10th of the month, a month is less than 10 of the year --> example: 5/9/18
**scenario 2:** when the date is >= 10th of the month, a month is less >= 10 of the year --> example: 10/11/18

Note: all the examples are in **MM/DD/YY** format and timezone is the USA

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();   
cal.add(Calendar.DATE,-2);    
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm a");   
String PastDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());  
info("Date is displayed as : "+ PastDate );
```

The above piece of code throwing me an error when the scenario 1 is in place. But if I format the date-time as "**M/d/yy H:mm a**" it works for both the scenario. I need the date add also.

Will it be a good practice to use the 2nd format? or there is any other way to get it done. Expert guidance please..

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Also rather than defining your own output format consider using one of the built-in formats you may get from `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Leading “0” in day of month SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836294/remove-leading-0-in-day-of-month-simpledateformat)

Comment: I cannot reproduce. From your code I get `Date is displayed as : 05/07/18 14:39 PM`. It’s not your desired output, I know, but no error gets thrown.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ole. I will try this. But I am not very familiar with these things. May ask you for your help in case I don't find a solution using DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime

Comment: Date is displayed as : 05/07/18 14:39 PM (it is as per your system date and time). The application I'm using displays as 5/7/18 14:39 PM

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
            .withLocale(Locale.US);
    ZonedDateTime dayBeforeYesterday = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/St_Thomas"))
            .minusDays(2);
    System.out.println(dayBeforeYesterday.format(formatter));
```

Running just now I got this output:

> 5/7/18, 8:44 AM

Please specify your desired time zone where I put America/St_Thomas. Think twice before you use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` for your JVM’s time zone setting since this setting may be changed at any time from other parts of your program or other programs running in the same JVM; but if you trust the setting reflects the user’s time zone, it’s the correct thing to use.

Rather than defining your own output format prefer using one of the built-in formats you get from `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`. Do specify locale (no matter if you use a built-in format or roll your own). Again, use `Locale.getDefault()` if you trust the JVM’s setting is correct.

Avoid the old date and time classes like `Calendar`, `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`. They are not only long outdated, they are also poorly designed and the last two in particular notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 0):

The number of characters in the format `MM` indicates that **two digits** are required in the input. A single character `M` will match **one** or **two** digits. Use `M/d/yy H:mm a` to support your desired formats.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Elliott. I will follow this approach then.